# Android - set imageView inside DialogFragment

Tags: android, imageview, android-dialogfragment

I have an application wherein I have a custom listView, upon clicking any item in the listView, a DialogFramgent is shown. Now, what I want to do is to set the imageView I have inside that DialogFramgent to an image in the external storage. I know that I can set the source of the imageView as such:

```
File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

However, I couldn't initialize my ImageView variable properly because findViewById gives an error: `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for type ItemDialog.

Here is the part in my custom listView onClickLisenter where I call my DialogFragment:

```
resultListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, final View v, final int position, long id) {

        positionSelected = position;

        SearchResultListViewItem selectedRow = results.get(position);
        String selectedItem = selectedRow.getItemName();
        itemBarcode = selectedRow.getBarcode();

        itemListDB.open();

        ItemDialog itemDialog = new ItemDialog();

        itemDialog.itemName = selectedItem;
        itemDialog.brandName = itemListDB.getBrandFromItemBarcode(itemBarcode);
        itemDialog.UOMName = itemListDB.getUOMFromItemBarcode(itemBarcode);
        itemDialog.priceName = itemListDB.getPriceFromItemBarcode(itemBarcode);
        itemDialog.discountName = itemListDB.getDiscountFromItemBarcode(itemBarcode);
        itemDialog.mListener = SearchResult.this;

        itemDialog.qtyFromList = qtyInput.get(position);
        itemDialog.discFromList = qtyInput.get(position);

        itemListDB.close();
        itemDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");

    }
});
```

and here is my ItemDialog class:

```
public class ItemDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{

    //my variables go over here

    public interface onSubmitListener {
        void setOnSubmitListener(String qty, String disc);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());  
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_item_dialog);  
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);

        File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.png");
        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }

        dialog.setTitle("Item Details");
        dialog.show();  
        //I set more variables here       
        return dialog;  
    }       

}
```

So, does anyone have an idea on how to set the source image of an imageView that's inside a DialogFragment? I'm stuck here and frankly, I have no idea how to proceed and I'll be really grateful if anyone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure your image exists in the path /sdcard/Images ?

Comment: Uh yes. The problem, as I said, is that there's a red underline in the findViweById when I try to look for the ImageView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `inflate` layout in your `Dialog Fragment` under `onCreateDialog(...)`

```
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View layout2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_filter_popup,null);

  dialog.setView(layout2);
```

and then reference your `Imageview` with that particular `layout`

```
   ImageView img=(ImageView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
```

**Update:**

```
@Override  
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());  

    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  


     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_filter_popup,null);
    dialog.setContentView(layout2);  

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) layout2.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);

    File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.png");

    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }

    dialog.setTitle("Item Details");
    dialog.show();  

    return dialog;  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but where exactly to I put this in my `onCreateDialog(..)` function?

Comment: Thank you. This works. I just changed the layout from `contact_filter_popup` to `fragment_item_dialog` (my own). Now I'm getting a NullPointer from the `myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);`. However, that's for another question altogether, I might be having problems with the path or something.

Comment: @Razgriz you have to change `contact_filter_popup` to your layout `fragment_item_dialog`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the lifecycle mismatch. In a dialog fragment when the dialog is created it doesn't mean the views are created. This will result in `IllegalArgumentException` due to fragment not attached to Activity. To overcome this always use/access your views after the views are inflated in the `onViewsCreated()/onCreateViews()` method. Find my solution below which works fine.

```
public class ImageDetailDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{

    private String url ;

    private ImageView imgProdDetail;


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        url = getArguments().getString("url");
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.product_dialog);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_dialog, null);
        imgProdDetail = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_prod_detail);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            /** Decode/load YOUR IMAGE HERE **/
        imgProdDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //not working
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        return dialog;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v!=imgProdDetail)
            this.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragments do not have the findViewById method, you can call it on the getView() method of th fragment:

```
  File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);
  if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
  }
```

I assume you already have inflated the corresponding view of the DialogFragment.

For more information:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

try to override the onCreateView() callback method, as a fragment, DialogFragment can be inflated with this method so you can later inlfate your layout and finding the imageview reference.